# add seconds to a date using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to find the End Time of a incoming visitor .  I have recorded the Intime & duration in My  DB through an API , But the API does not provide the option for End Time. It looks like i have to calculate the End time, from ( Intime & Duration ) . However i did find the end time. But it is taking too much time to process the code and i am geting  error like **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 600 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\logmein\ on line 68** .

Please look into my code and tellme a way to customize my Code in a very easier way.

Start time-11/19/2014 4:57 AM,Duration-1423

I want :Start time:2014-11-20 12:48:17,
End Time:2014-11-20 13:07:17,
Duration-00:19:35

```
<?php
$WaitingTime=1423;
$i = ($WaitingTime / 60) % 60;
$duration = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($WaitingTime / 3600), ($WaitingTime / 60 % 60), $WaitingTime % 60);
 $timestamp = strtotime($strat_time);
 $chat_start=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
$time = new DateTime($chat_start);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $i . 'M'));
 $chat_end = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: your question isn't clearly. This method maybe helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks all,This is my answer.**

```
<?php
$WaitingTime=1423;
$strat_time="11/19/2014 2:49:23";
$dateinsec=strtotime($strat_time);
$newdate=$dateinsec+$WaitingTime;
$chat_start=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateinsec);
$chat_end= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$newdate);
$duration = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($WaitingTime / 3600), ($WaitingTime / 60 % 60), $WaitingTime % 60);
                    <?
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following achieves this:

```
<?php

$durationSeconds = 1423;

$startDateString = '11/19/2014 4:57 AM';
$startTime = new DateTime($startDateString);
$startString = $startTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$duration = new DateInterval('PT'.$durationSeconds.'S');
$hours = floor($durationSeconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($durationSeconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
$seconds = $durationSeconds % 60;
$durationString = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;

$startTime->add($duration);
$endString = $startTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my answer2**

```
$time1 = strtotime("$call_start");
$time2 = strtotime($call_end);
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
 $ath = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($diff / 3600), ($diff / 60 % 60), $diff % 60);
```